# How does the new "smart" quest sorting in Warlords of Draenor work?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

A preview of the Quest Log in Warlords of Draenor states the following:

> In Patch 6.0.2, we’ve made a brand-new UI to bring together the Map and the Quest Log with everything you need to manage multiple ongoing adventures. Now when you browse by zone in the Map & Quest Log, you’ll find all of the associated quests you’re on, your progress, and relevant cartography.
>
> In addition to intelligently ordering your quests, the new window (default hotkeys: M or L) gives you more information about your objectives right on the map. It also features scroll-wheel zooming, click-and-hold panning, and a handy View All Quests button—plus, if you leave it open while you’re moving, it fades so that you can see both the map and the landscape you’re venturing into.

In Mists of Pandaria, I can choose to order quests by proximity, and then if I've selected the top quest (which has the closest objective), once I've completed it, my active objective automatically moves to the next closest quest—and as I move around, if a particular quest is now closer, it moves to the top of my quest tracker, and and I can change my active quest to that one.

Here's a screenshot of the quest log from the beta, though:

[image: The Warlords of Draenor quest log in action]

As you can see, the top quest in my quest tracker on the right is close to my current location, but the map shows that I have a completed quest ready for turn-in considerably closer. While the tracker has definitely changed the order of displayed quests, I can't tell *why* it's ordering quests in the way that it is, and I no longer have the option of changing the order of displayed quests.

So: how does the sorting algorithm decide how to order my currently displayed quests?

Comment: Isn't WoD in closed beta?

Comment: @RandomDisplayName Warlords of Draenor is, yes, but patch 6.0.2 is not. This (Patch 6.0.2) is currently in PTR and very much playable.

Comment: Patch 6.0.2 is the Pre-Expansion patch. This will start the development of the world/events into the new Expansion.

Comment: @HowlinWulf True but the way that it's worded implies that the screenshot is from the beta itself, which if true would constitute a breach of the NDA (and also be off-topic).

Comment: @JonK Perhaps, although I was on PTR this morning, and just now again, and that looks like a screenshot off PTR (6.0.2).

Comment: The new quest system is being added in Patch 6.0.2, yes, and is accessible through the PTR. However, as I have the Warlords of Draenor Beta client installed (and not the PTR client), that's where I took the screenshot. The system is supposed to work the same in both systems, and if it doesn't, that might help answer my question. In any event, the WoD Beta has no NDA: http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/14605867/world-of-warcraft%C2%AE-warlords-of-draenor%E2%84%A2-beta-test-begins-6-27-2014

Comment: This is only a guess, but is it possible the sorting algorithm optimises the quests turn ins? Meaning it's not showing the turn in at the top because if you finish the other quests first, you'll be able to turn them all in at the same time and start on the next bunch of semi-related quests

Comment: @JonK There is no NDA on the Warlords of Draenor beta. Blizzard has explicitly stated that [beta testers are free to share whatever they like](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/13019672288).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [6.0.2 PTR patch notes](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/15682579),

> Quest tracker now orders quests based on proximity to the character by default.

From playing on the beta, I suspect that quests which are "ready for turn-in" either do not count, or perhaps there is still a bug.

In general, though, I find it preferable to stay out in the world, complete a bunch of quests, and then turn them in all at once, when it's possible to do so. So this ordering really doesn't bother me.

---

You should also note that:

- By default you only see quests which are in your current zone (in Draenor; doesn't seem to apply consistently in Azeroth). You can click the View All button to see the entire list.
- Some quests are not offered at quest hubs, but at random points out in the world. Check your map frequently for these. Usually you'll have to pass by them while doing other quests, but I saw a few exceptions.